# Publish react library to local server instead of npm or gemfury

Tags: reactjs

I will be creating a React UI library. Is it possible to publish this library to a local server and then install it from that local server into another React project?
I am aware it can be published in npm or gemfury but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) to generate a tarball of the library. Then copy that gzipped tarball to your local server. Then use [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) pointed to the location of the gzipped tarball to install the package.

If your local server exposes the tarballs via HTTP you can use `npm install http://local-server/path/to/mylibrary-1.0.1.tgz` otherwise you’ll have to have a way to copy the tarball locally or access the tarball directly when performing a `npm install /path/to/mylibrary-1.0.1.tgz`.